# argparser n iteration of arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am struggling with one thing about `argparser` and I cannot find anything — for sure I don’t know how to correctly call it. I would like to do some "iteration" of arguments — the main goal is to keep positional arguments.

e.g. I have arguments like:

```
parser.add_argument("volume", action=„append”, nargs=„*”)
parser.add_argument("-host", action=„append”, nargs=„*”)
parser.add_argument("-device", action=„append”, nargs=„*”)
```

Parsing via CLI:

```
python assing.py (2000 2001 -host HOST1) (2002 -host HOST2 HOST3) -device DEV1
```

Get something like:

```
List of iteration for specific arguments:
[{"volume": ["2000", "2001"], "host": ["HOST1"]},
{"volume": ["2002"], "host": ["HOST2", "HOST2"]}]
Device arguments:
{"device": ["DEV1"]}
```

Result of arguments will be use in this way:

```
for device in devices:
    for iteration in iterations:
        for host in hosts:
            for volume in volumes:
                assign(volume, host, device)
```

and I want to avoid situation like assign all volumes to all hosts, that’s I prefer somehow group/separate arguments

Unlucky, I can realise it only by not using positional arguments in this way:

```
python assign.py -volume 2000 2001 -host HOST1 -volume 2002 -host HOST2 HOST3 -device DEV1

print({vars(args)})

{'volume': [['2000', '2001'], ['2002’]], 'host': [['HOST1'], ['HOST2', 'HOST3']], 
 'device': ['DEV1’]}
```

Then I can simply separate assigning volumes 2000, 2001 to HOST1 and 2002 to HOST2 & HOST3 but what’s about keep positional arguments? Is it possible to do some break append like ")(" with custom action? I know that I cannot pass positional after append argument like:

```
"(2000 2001 -host HOST1 )( 2002 -host"
```

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` to see what the parser has to work with.  You can't group arguments.  And 'append' does not make sense with a `positional`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use those arguments in bash:

```
1651:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py (2000 2001 -host HOST1) (2002 -host HOST2 HOST3) -device DEV1
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

with quotes:

```
1651:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py '(2000 2001 -host HOST1)' '(2002 -host HOST2 HOST3)' -device DEV1
['echo.py', '(2000 2001 -host HOST1)', '(2002 -host HOST2 HOST3)', '-device', 'DEV1']
```

without ()

```
1653:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py 2000 2001 -host HOST1 2002 -host HOST2 HOST3 -device DEV1
['echo.py', '2000', '2001', '-host', 'HOST1', '2002', '-host', 'HOST2', 'HOST3', '-device', 'DEV1']
```